# How to make a list of strings using a 'ScrollView' (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, string, textview, android-studio

In my Layout I have made a `TextView` which is meant to contain a large amount of text.
Under the `TextView` I added this two characteristics:

```
android:maxLines = "100"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:text="@string/infoestring"
```

and this in the Java file:

```
TextView INFO=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
INFO.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

All that just to make like a `ScrollView` in the `TextView(info)` and it
works just fine. The problem is in my `strings.xml` file under the directory `Values`.
I have the String named `'infostring'`:

```
<string name="infostring">A:B:C:D:E:F:G:H:I:J:K:L:M:N:O:P:Q:R:S:T:U:V:W:X:Y:Z:</string>
```

The `TextView` is wide and what I want is to put every Letter(From the string `'infostring'`) **in one single line of the `TextView`**, I try adding spaces between the letters in the string but it doesn't work, is there a way to do it?.

Comment: Add this properties android:singleLine="true" and remove android:maxLines = "100" to TextView in xml.

Comment: do you mean you want **each** letter its own line?

Comment: so you have to shown each letter in each line then simple add "\n" before each character otherwise just what i say in first comment.

Comment: and why would you want such a `TextView` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each letter on a line, how about :

```
<string name="infostring">"A\nB\nC\nD\nE"</string>
```

But I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here, it looks painful to do. There should be another solution for your bigger problem.

To actually make a list of strings, you should [check out `ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), which takes care of the scrolling and everything.

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks. I will try the ListView too. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) `ListView` is the standard component for scrollable lists, which handles views recycling etc. You should definitely have a look ;)